# Phonegap android ajax not works on android device

Tags: php, android, jquery, ajax, cordova

I had created an example in which i had made a simple ajax call to send data to android app.
here is the ajax function:

```
function testServer()
{
    var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.1","Test Exmple", 500000);
    $.ajax({
        url: urlServer+'getTest.php',
        contentType : 'application/json',
        dataType: 'json',
        data : {companyCode : 'Template'},
        success : function(data){
            alert(data);
        },
        error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

            console.log("Server is not responding... Please try after sometime"+thrownError);

        }
    });
}
```

here is the php code:

```
<?
 require_once ('connect.php');
 include("AES.class.php");
 $companyurl =$_REQUEST['companyCode'];

 $data = $companyurl;

 require_once('JSON.php');
 $json = new Services_JSON();
  echo ($json->encode($data));
 ?>
```

here is the logcat :

```
 06-05 16:59:27.165: E/CordovaWebView(23703): CordovaWebView: TIMEOUT ERROR!
 06-05 16:59:27.165: D/Cordova(23703): CordovaWebViewClient.onReceivedError: Error code=-6 Description=The connection to the server was unsuccessful. URL=file:///android_asset/www/TestComp.html
 06-05 16:59:27.165: D/DroidGap(23703): onMessage(onReceivedError,{"errorCode":-6,"url":"file:\/\/\/android_asset\/www\/TestComp.html","description":"The connection to the server was unsuccessful."})
 06-05 16:59:27.255: D/skia(23703): notifyPluginsOnFrameLoad not postponed
 06-05 16:59:27.416: D/SoftKeyboardDetect(23703): Ignore this event
 06-05 16:59:27.416: D/CordovaLog(23703): Server is not responding... Please try after sometime
 06-05 16:59:27.416: I/Web Console(23703): Server is not responding... Please try after sometime at file:///android_asset/www/TestComp.html:24
 06-05 16:59:27.426: D/Cordova(23703): onPageFinished(file:///android_asset/www/TestComp.html)
 06-05 16:59:27.426: D/DroidGap(23703): onMessage(onPageFinished,file:///android_asset/www/TestComp.html)
 06-05 16:59:27.486: I/Adreno200-EGLSUB(23703): <ConfigWindowMatch:2078>: Format RGBA_8888.
 06-05 16:59:27.496: D/memalloc(23703): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x51f47000 size:675840 fd:124
 06-05 16:59:27.526: D/OpenGLRenderer(23703): has fontRender patch
 06-05 16:59:27.596: D/OpenGLRenderer(23703): has fontRender patch
 06-05 16:59:27.626: D/memalloc(23703): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5460c000 size:675840 fd:130
 06-05 16:59:28.687: D/memalloc(23703): ashmem: Mapped buffer base:0x5470c000 size:675840 fd:133
```

But it works perfectly on the emulator.

Can any one help me to find the problem.

Thanks in advance

Comment: super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html"); add this in android activity

Comment: @Harini Sekar I had already add this property

Comment: Check you have set the permission for INTERNET_CONNECTION in your AndroidManifest file

Comment: refer : https://www.robertkehoe.com/2013/01/fix-for-phonegap-connection-to-server-was-unsuccessful/

Comment: Permission for INTERNET_CONNECTION and for STORAGE were also set in AndroidManifest file-

Answer (score 0):

refer : http://rickluna.com/wp/2012/04/solving-the-connection-to-the-server-was-unsuccessful-error-in-androidphonegap/

```
super.setIntegerProperty("loadUrlTimeoutValue", 60000);
super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Cross domain request.
So, try to change  dataType from 'json' to  '**jsonp**'.
Here I updated your code :

```
function testServer()
{
var db = window.openDatabase("Database", "1.1","Test Exmple", 500000);
$.ajax({
    url: urlServer+'getTest.php',
    contentType : 'application/json',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    data : {companyCode : 'Template'},
    success : function(data){
        alert(data);
    },
    error : function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {

        console.log("Server is not responding... Please try after     sometime"+thrownError);

    }
});
}
```

Comment: know its giving error Connection to the server was unsuccessful.

Comment: Can you please try by removing line: contentType : "application/json"

Answer (score 0):

Guys thanks for your help there was no error in the code the issue was with the firewall just gave access to the port in firewall and it worked perfectly.
Once again thanks for your help.